# Выбор случайного элемента массива, вероятность выпадания которого предопределена

Tags: php, массивы, случайные-числа

Есть такой набор данных:

```
$items = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Элемент #1',
        'chance' => 1,
        ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Элемент #2',
        'chance' => 5,
        ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Элемент #3',
        'chance' => 10,
        ),
    );
```

Для каждого элемента массива предопределена вероятность — в ключе `'chance'`.

Задача: выбрать случайный элемент из этого набора, учитывая, что вероятность того что выпадет «Элемент #2» в 5 раз выше, чем «Элемент #1», а «Элемент #3» — в 10 раз выше, чем у «Элемент #1».

Если точнее, то, наверно, так:

- Элемент #1 — вероятность: 1/16
- Элемент #2 — вероятность: 5/16
- Элемент #3 — вероятность: 10/16

Набросал [такой алгоритм](http://ideone.com/iMfyRr):

```
$items = [...];  // входной массив (см. выше)


$items_set = array();

foreach ($items as $item_id => $item)
    {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $item['chance']; $i++)
        $items_set[] = $item_id;
    }

// теперь $items_set представляет собой такой массив:
// [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
// то бишь, индекс элемента входного массива повторяется столько,
// сколько у него «шансов» быть избранным

$rand_id = $items_set[array_rand($items_set)];
$rand_item = $items[$rand_id];
```

На выходе `$rand_item` хранит как-раз то, что необходимо — один из элементов входного массива. И все бы хорошо, если бы при добавлении элемента с вероятностью 200, массив `$items_set` не рос на 200 элементов. И таких может быть несколько.

Вопрос: есть ли какой-то более адекватный способ решения задачи?
Если алгоритм будет уметь оперировать с элементами с вероятностью = 0.5 — будет вообще здорово (мой вариант к этому не приспособлен, приходится предварительно подбирать множитель для всех «шансов» так, чтобы минимальный был = 1).

Comment: спасибо большое автору вопроса. У меня почти такая же задача, только я раздаю юзерам награду. Я посмотрел на ответы и понял, что Ваш алгоритм намного справедливее и правильне чем остальные ответы. Я сам сразу додумался всем признаного ответа. А теперь пример: Первый - шанс 43, второй - 56. И того массив {43, 100}. В итоге почти всегда, тот кто получил меньше очков забрал всю награду. Но согласно теории вероятности, чем больше итераций, тем вернее шанс. Потому Ваш алгоритм с получения массива $items_set[] справедливе и вернее.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

да, такой алгоритм есть. Он заключается в том, что нужно сформировать массив вида [1,6,16]. ( То есть, если есть массив вероятностей [1,5,10], то нужный массив это такой, что элемент в позиции `n` - это сумма элементов первого массива от 1 до n). Последний элемент этого массива - это суммарное кол-во вариантов.

Как использвоать:

генерируем случайное число и проходим по массиву, пока не найдем элемент, который больше сгенерированного числа (я предполагаю, что случайные числа генерятся в диапазоне от 0 до сумма минус 1).

Но если элементов больше 7-10, то лучше уже подумать о бинарном поиске, благое дело, он будет быстрым (массив то гарантированно отсортирован).

Comment: Шикарно! Интереса ради пойду попробую, сравню со своим. Спасибо.

Comment: Проблема с массивом вероятностей вида [1,5,5,10] (то есть, я добавил еще один элемент, вероятность которого такая же, как у 2-го).

Как в таком случае быть? Все так же составлять массив [1,6,16], а потом в случае, если случайное число будет = 5, то среди 2-х отобранных элементов тоже выбирать случайный? Или есть способ хитрее?

Comment: В таком случае массив интервалов будет  

    [1, 6, 11, 21]
Создается он примерно так:  

    $ver_array= Array(1, 5, 5, 10);
    $range_ver_array= Array();
    foreach ($var_array as $k=>$v)
        if ($k==0) {
            $range_ver_array[]=$v;
        } else {
            $range_ver_array[]=$range_ver_array[$k-1]+$v;
        };

Comment: Нужно правильно сформировать массив. Он будет таким [1,6,11,21]. То есть, если `a` - это массив вероятностей, а `b` - это нужный нам массив, то `b[i] = a[0] + a[1] + .. a[i]`.

Comment: Разве при этом не появляется у одного из «равновесных» элементов преимущества перед другим?

Comment: если rand выдает равномернораспределенное значение на интервале, то все по честному, и порядок вероятностей в массиве не имеет значения.

Comment: Нет. Равновесным элементам будут отведены одинаковые по длине интервалы. Вероятности попадания в них случайного числа с равномерным распределением равны.

Comment: Дополнительный массив для этого алгоритма не нужен. Поиск интервала можно осуществлять по исходному массиву поочередно вычитая из рандомного числа значения вероятностей в исходном массиве, сравнивая накопленную разность с нулем.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте хранить интервалы вероятностей для каждого элемента:

1. Элемент №1 - от 0 (включительно) до 1 (не вкл.)
2. Элемент №2 - от 1 (вкл.) до 6 (не вкл.)
3. Элемент №3 - от 6 (вкл.) до 16 (не вкл.)

Теперь ваша задача заключается в том, чтобы взять случайное число от 0 до 15, проверить, в какой интервал оно попадает и взять соответствующий элемент.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но понятно, что можно было бы использовать и диапазоны, но тут суровость возникнет при попытке определить, в какой же именно интервал оно попадает

Comment: А в чём проблема-то? Храните только верхнюю границу интервала, а при поиске вам надо будет просто найти минимальное число в массиве вероятностей такое, что сгенерированное случайное число меньше его. По сути мой способ аналогичен способу, предложенному @KoVadim, но он сразу перешёл к верхним границам интервалов.

Answer (score 0):

Решил похожую задачу просто -  указал диапазон чисел для слов. 
Чем больше диапазон чисел для слова, тем больше вероятность его вывода.

```
$bb = rand(0,1000);

if ($bb >= 0 && $bb <= 700) {
   echo "значение 1 ".$bb;
}

elseif ($bb >= 701 && $bb <= 1000) {
   echo "значение 2 ".$bb;
}
```

Comment: Конечно. Дело в том, что у меня был неупорядоченный набор. Хотя я и об этом забыл упомянуть в описании вопроса, вариант, предложенный в первом же ответе, был приспособлен к этому (за исключением бинарного поиска).