# Генерация случайных чисел с дискретным распределением вероятностей

Tags: java

Как на java сгенерировать одно из двух случайных чисел. Генерировать надо только 2 или 4. Прчем генерировать надо с задааной вероятностью — 90 процентов генерация 2ки и с 10 процентной вероятностью генерация 4ки.

Comment: Не совсем копия, но там (наверно) Вы найдете принцип, как решить задачу: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/212295/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае решается как-то так:

```
Random r = new Random(); // заведите общий экземпляр на программу

double total = 90 + 10;
double random = r.nextDouble() * total;
if (random < 90)
    return 2;
else
    return 4;
```

Решение естественным образом обобщается на массив значений и «весов»:

```
double total = DoubleStream.of(weight).sum();
double random = r.nextDouble() * total;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    random -= weight[i];
    if (random < 0)
        return value[i];
}
```

Comment: можно "покороче" : `return (random<90)? 2: 4` вместо блока if-else :)

Comment: @pavlofff: Это да, но идея с последовательными проверками обобщается на произвольное количество значений.

Comment: @VladD. Да, был неправ. Предыдущий коммент удалил. Как вариант, можно было не лезть в дроби, а использовать `r.nextInt(0, 101)`.

Comment: @VeLKerr: Это да, но я подумал о случае, когда веса могут быть дробными. Например, 33.333333333%.

Comment: @VladD, да в этом случае применение дробей оправдано.